# Can GLSL support switch statements implemented as jump tables?

Tags: glsl, gpu, gpgpu

Looks like not on AMD a few years ago (["the switch-statement into jump table optimization is not done by our driver"](http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/143080)).

From what I've seen of Nvidia's intermediate language (via `glGetProgramBinary` or `export __GL_WriteProgramObjectAssembly=1`) there's no dynamic jump command, or at least I can't trigger it. Functions aren't possible (they all get inlined, I assume this is due to the lack of a dynamic jump for returning) and switch statements seem wind up as nested if-statements. **Is it at all possible to trigger a switch statement to jump dynamically?** (unlike the following)

```
#version 430

uniform int index;

void main()
{
    switch(index)
    {
    case 0: gl_Position.x = 0; break;
    case 1: gl_Position.x = 1; break;
    case 2: gl_Position.x = 2; break;
    case 3: gl_Position.x = 3; break;
    }
}
```

...

```
!!NVvp5.0
OPTION NV_bindless_texture;
OPTION NV_shader_atomic_float;
 PARAM c[1] = { program.local[0] };
TEMP R0;
TEMP RC, HC;
SEQ.S R0.x, c[0], {0, 0, 0, 0};
MOV.U.CC RC.x, -R0;
IF NE.x;
MOV.F result.position.x, {0, 0, 0, 0};
ELSE;
SEQ.S R0.x, c[0], {1, 0, 0, 0};
MOV.U.CC RC.x, -R0;
IF NE.x;
MOV.F result.position.x, {1, 0, 0, 0};
ELSE;
SEQ.S R0.x, c[0], {2, 0, 0, 0};
MOV.U.CC RC.x, -R0;
IF NE.x;
MOV.F result.position.x, {2, 0, 0, 0};
ELSE;
SEQ.S R0.x, c[0], {3, 0, 0, 0};
MOV.U.CC RC.x, -R0;
IF NE.x;
MOV.F result.position.x, {3, 0, 0, 0};
ENDIF;
ENDIF;
ENDIF;
ENDIF;
END
```

I can kind of understand this - a SIMT architecture wouldn't be much good if every thread was executing arbitrary code. Then again, there's dynamic loops and branching. Perhaps it's just easier to track divergence so threads can sync up at some point?

A further question, how does CUDA do function pointers on the same hardware? Is there something in the GLSL specs prohibiting this or is there no one left working on shader compilers these days?

Comment: Note that, since the vertex program has only been compiled to an intermediate language, the switch statement may still be optimized further during final compilation and optimization.

Comment: @RogerDahl good point, do you know if there's a way to dig deeper and see the code further down the pipeline?

Comment: I don't know how to get to the SASS machine code in the OpenGL stack. With CUDA, SASS for specific targets can be embedded in the binary and dynamically compiled for targets that were unknown when the binary was created. You can keep a copy of the SASS during compilation or disassemble it from the binary later. I think there is also a way to get to the SASS from PTX dynamically compiled by the driver.